# django custom user model gives me lazy reference error

Tags: python, django

My code is as shown below:

models/user.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,BaseUserManager
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email,and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save(using=self._db)
                return user
        except:
            raise

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
```

models/**init**.py

```
 from user import User
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]



AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'dashboard.User'
```

After this when I run `python manage.py migrate`, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 164, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 218, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 295, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'dashboard.user', but app 'dashboard' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'dashboard.user', but app 'dashboard' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Is it because of improper jwt token configuration or user model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retrieving your User model with get_user_model?

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: When I put the lines suggested by you in my models/user.py , it gives me `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'dashboard.User' that has not been installed` error